# Athena classic load balancer logs

Tags: logging, amazon-athena

I used this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/elasticloadbalancer-classic-logs.html) to successfully query classic load balancing logs, however as the bucket has increased in size I want to partition my table.  Unfortunately I can't get it to work and would appreciate some advice.

The following is an attempt to create a partitioned table but it is created but returns 0 rows:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `elb_logs_part`( 
`timestamp` string COMMENT '', 
  `elb_name` string COMMENT '', 
  `request_ip` string COMMENT '', 
  `request_port` int COMMENT '', 
  `backend_ip` string COMMENT '', 
  `backend_port` int COMMENT '', 
  `request_processing_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `backend_processing_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `client_response_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `elb_response_code` string COMMENT '', 
  `backend_response_code` string COMMENT '', 
  `received_bytes` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `sent_bytes` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `request_verb` string COMMENT '', 
  `url` string COMMENT '', 
  `protocol` string COMMENT '', 
  `user_agent` string COMMENT '', 
  `ssl_cipher` string COMMENT '', 
  `ssl_protocol` string COMMENT '')
PARTITIONED BY(year string, month string, day string)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \\\"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\\\" (\"[^\"]*\") ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1555268331')
```

I have tried editing to add the region to the end of the location (this seems logical but the above was created out of the create query athena produced so I went with it).

I have tried to alter the existing table as well using:

```sql
ALTER TABLE elb_logs.elb_logs ADD 
   PARTITION(year='2019' month = '11', day = '18') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
   PARTITION(year='2019' month = '11', day = '17') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
   PARTITION(year='2019' month = '11', day = '16') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
```

Unfortunately this produces the error:

> line 2:4: missing 'column' at 'partition'"

which I don't understand as the above is taken directly from documentation.  I imagine it is caused by the partitions not being defined or something...!?

Sorry all new to me, can anyone help me to partition a classic load balancer logs stored in s3 using Athena?

Really need to spot the buggers who keep scraping my sites and I think unintentionally taking us offline!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing comma (`,`) after you specify `year`. The following statement resulted in **Query successful**.

```sql
ALTER TABLE elb_logs.elb_logs ADD 
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '18') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '17') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '16') location 's3://buckets/bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/eu-west-1/2019/11/17'
```

Comment: Ah jeez - of course! That saves as expected but now when I try a basic query all I get is "Something went wrong"...which is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Although, I defined table schema in glue meta catalog, I wasn't able to actually test this table with some query, as I don't have any underlying data for it. Have you solved your next issue?)

Answer (score 0):

For me to partition the data I needed I had to take 2 steps, firstly create a new partitioned table but pointing to the wrong location, then add the correct partitions.

Step 1: Create partitioned table (note the location is actually not ideal, excluding the region)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `elb_logs_part`(
  `timestamp` string COMMENT '', 
  `elb_name` string COMMENT '', 
  `request_ip` string COMMENT '', 
  `request_port` int COMMENT '', 
  `backend_ip` string COMMENT '', 
  `backend_port` int COMMENT '', 
  `request_processing_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `backend_processing_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `client_response_time` double COMMENT '', 
  `elb_response_code` string COMMENT '', 
  `backend_response_code` string COMMENT '', 
  `received_bytes` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `sent_bytes` bigint COMMENT '', 
  `request_verb` string COMMENT '', 
  `url` string COMMENT '', 
  `protocol` string COMMENT '', 
  `user_agent` string COMMENT '', 
  `ssl_cipher` string COMMENT '', 
  `ssl_protocol` string COMMENT '')
  PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \\\"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\\\" (\"[^\"]*\") ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*)$') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1555268331')
```

Step 2: Partition the data as below (thanks to Ilya for spotting the typo)

```
ALTER TABLE elb_logs.elb_logs_part ADD 
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '18') location 's3://bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/region/2019/11/18'
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '17') location 's3://bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/region/2019/11/17'
   PARTITION(year='2019', month = '11', day = '16') location 's3://bucketname/AWSLogs/XXXXXXXXX/elasticloadbalancing/region/2019/11/16'
```

This worked for me.